# Exportação .csv com complemento de linhas com base em um número fixo

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Tenho uma tabela no MySQL de produtos. Preciso criar uma exportação .csv deles.

Os produtos estão no banco da seguinte forma:

```
cod    produto    valor    pagina
123    caderno     1,00    1
456    lápis       1,00    1
789    borracha    1,00    1
1122   régua       1,00    2
1123   cola        1,00    2
1122   caneta      1,00    3
```

Preciso definir uma quantidade fixa de linhas por página. Quando o limite não for atingido preciso completar com espaços vazios. Vamos imaginar que o limite seja 5.

Esperado:

```
cod    produto    valor    pagina
123    caderno     1,00    1
456    lápis       1,00    1
789    borracha    1,00    1
 -        -          -     -
 -        -          -     -
1122   régua       1,00    2
1122   cola        1,00    2
 -        -          -     -
 -        -          -     -
 -        -          -     -
 1122   caneta      1,00   3
 -        -          -     -
 -        -          -     -
 -        -          -     -
 -        -          -     -
 -        -          -     -
```

Isso pode ser feito no MySQL ou PHP, mas alguém tem ideia de como eu poderia fazer?

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
$pagina = 0;
$quantidade = 24;
$inicio     =  ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;
$export = $conn->prepare("SELECT 
  f.prod_produto,f.prod_marca,
  f.prod_tipo1,f.prod_tipo2,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.prod_preco,'.',1) AS prod_preco,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.prod_preco,'.',-1) AS prod_centavos,
  REPLACE(f.prod_gramatura,',','.') AS prod_gramatura,  
  (CASE 
  WHEN f.prod_pais = 0 THEN 'BRA' ELSE   p.iso3
  END) AS pais,
  prod_pagina AS pagina
  FROM 
  produto AS f
  LEFT JOIN cep_paises AS p
  ON p.numcode = f.prod_pais
  WHERE
  prod_periodo = '16'
  ORDER BY prod_pagina ASC
  LIMIT  $inicio,$quantidade");
$export->execute(array());


while($dados = $export->fetch()){
   //exibe produtos
  echo $dados[0]."<br>";
}
if($export->rowCount() < $quantidade){
  $conta = $quantidade - $export->rowCount();
  while($conta <= $quantidade){
    echo $conta++;
        //preenche as linhas em branco
  }
}
```

Isso me provoca o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-24,24' at
>   line 18' in
>   C:\Users\server\htdocs\sistemas\modulos\produtos\export.php:92 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\Users\server\htdocs\sistemas\modulos\produtos\export.php(92):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\Users\server\htdocs\sistemas\modulos\produtos\export.php on line 92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$paginaAtual = "";
$limite = 5;
$conta = 0;
while($dados = $export->fetch()){
   //exibe produtos
  if($paginaAtual ==""){ //define a primeira pagina
      $paginaAtual = $dados["pagina"];
      $conta = 0;
  }elseif($paginaAtual != $dados['pagina']){//verifica se mudou de pagina
       while($conta < $limite){ // verifica se ficou algum item a menos
           echo "-        -          -     -"
            $conta++;
       }
       $paginaAtual = $dados["pagina"];
       $conta = 0;
  }
   $conta++
  echo $dados["produto"]."<br>";
}
while($conta < $limite){ // verifica pela ultima vez
       echo "-        -          -     -"
        $conta++;
   }
```

Comment: O que seria:  CAMPO == CAMPO2 ?

Comment: vc pode substituir por variaveis q deseja utilizar ai $val == $val2

Comment: retornou um erro ao tentar fazer, anexei o erro na sua resposta, sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: Adicionei a minha pergunta a query original para você ver como ficou

Comment: oi, qual erro não estou vendo aqui

Comment: Adicionei a minha pergunta, tinha adicionado na sua mais não mostrou mesmo.

Comment: Parece que tem algo de errado com o limit  -24,24 ele limite é essas suas linhas:   $quantidade = 24;
 $inicio     =  ($quantidade * $pagina) - $quantidade;

Comment: "-24,24"  no seu limit está sendo passado um valor negativo, tente alterar o valor de pagina $pagina = 0;  para $pagina = 1;

Comment: Parou de dar erro , mais não esta contando os vazios

Comment: Entendi o que aconteceu, ela não esta quebrando as paginas como no exemplo acima, ele calcula os 24 como um todo, mais preciso que ele calcule pela coluna pagina como mostrado no exemplo

Comment: Veja, aumentei as quantidades e retornou: rowcount50
quantidade50 , a quantidade de paginas que eu coloco ele vai somando as paginas ao inves de quebra-las como eu quero

Comment: alterei a resposta, remove o limit do seu SQL, e altera o seu while

Comment: 90% , porque deu certo, mais somente na primeira pagina, por exemplo, no meu caso na pagina 06 teria que acontecer essa regra mais não foi, ja quebrei a cabela nos loops mais não encontrei o que poderia ser

Comment: deixa eu entender somente  na  ultima  pagina  não está acontecendo o preenchimento das linhas restantes ?

Comment: sim, mais é porque assim, meu limite é 24 com isso na pagina 1 tem 10 ele completa, a pagina 3 tem 24, a pagina 3 tem 24, e por ai vai, na pagina 6 tem 9 ele deveria completar até 24 mais não completou

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70510/discussion-between-otacio-barbosa-and-marcos-brinner-pikatoons).